# Does BEACON from the EPA have an API?

Tags: api, rest, soap

I found a page for BEACON which has a fairly complete list of beaches inside the app itself:

http://iaspub.epa.gov/waters10/beacon_national_page.main

However, I can't seem to find anyplace that this page actually pulls data from.  I'd like to be able to use this data for a personal project.  Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

BEACON 2.0 will be released soon. It will provide links to the three databases from which data is pulled. For a dataflow diagram see
http://water.epa.gov/grants_funding/beachgrants/upload/2009_08_13_beaches_grants_datausers_2009_ebeaches_flow.pdf